# How to rename the file name with timestamp of created date by JavaScript, Perl or shell on OSX?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, javascript

Could you tell me how to get timestamp of created date of file and rename the file name with it by JavaScript, Perl or shell on OSX 10.9.2?

**Example:**

Existing: Untitled.txt   timestamp is 2014/05/03 01:01:01

New: %prefix%_Untitled_20140503_0101.txt (seconds is not necessary)

**Reason:**

I'm having strange things that the timestamp is changed looks by microwave/V2K technology frequently. But I have to know when it's created. because these are evidence of the matter.
Please kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the creation time of the file use `stat` command. The output will be in seconds (since unix epoch).

- `-n` option suppresses the newline at end of output.
- `-f` permits use of "printf" formatting. `%B` is the creation or "birth" date of the file.

  ```
  D=$(stat -nf'%B' your_file)
  ```

Then use date `-r` option to input date in seconds. The `+%Y...` aargument specifies the date format.

```
   DF=$(date -r $D '+%Y%m%d_%H%M')
```

The bash scripting would be something like this-:

```
 export PREFIX="your_prefix"
 D=$(stat -nf'%B' your_file)            # seconds since creation time of file
 DF=$(date -r $D '+%Y%m%d_%H%M')             # formatted creation date/time
 mv your_file "${PREFIX}_your_file_${DF}.txt"  # rename the file
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but What I would like to know how to read the time stamp of file and rename the file name with time stamp. sorry about my English.

Comment: No worries - sorry about the confusion. I've changed the answer to suit your requirements.

Comment: No problem - I'm happy you have a solution.